# simple example of puppet package

Tags: puppet

can some one tell me how to create a simple puppet package? My requirement is like below

I've some files that needs to copy from one location to another location.

How do I write a script by using puppet package?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a Puppet module. A quick look in the documentation leads to:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/modules_fundamentals.html